# What does 'MM' means when I run a svn diff?

Tags: svn, diff

When I run `svn diff` with the `--summarize` argument,

```
svn diff --summarize <path1> <path2>
```

I see some lines starting with `MM` in the output.

I know `M` is for modified, `D` for deleted, etc. but I have never seen `MM` before.

Does anyone know what `MM` means ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

the first column is content, the 2nd is properties

so your content, and its properties, have been modified.

Comment: svn diff --summarize outputs the list of changed files in the output format of svn status. see http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re26.html for full listing of columns